# Go Cron Singleton Mode() vs Singleton Mode All()

Tags: go, cron

I want to use Scheduler in GO Lang with gocron package.
And when I want to using Job Singleton Mode there are 2 types:

- `SingletonMode()`
- `SingletoModeAll()`

I just want to know what is the difference between these two methods.

Answer (score 1):

- SingletonMode(): This is when you're setting it on a single job.
- SingletoModeAll(): This is when you want to set it for all jobs on that scheduler.

Take a look at the examples:

- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-co-op/gocron#example-Scheduler.SingletonMode
- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-co-op/gocron#example-Scheduler.SingletonModeAll